# Minecraft black terrain and texture bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My minecraft has a problem with its textures, when I hold an item or even see my inventory the texture is not like vanilla minecraft. The other bug is that I'm surrounded with black terrain when I walk and even when I spawn. I tried downloading Minecraft again but nothing happened. I used the Atlantiumcraft mode and I uninstalled it and I used faithful texture pack and I uninstalled too maybe it corrupted. If so how can I fix this?

Here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you been using any custom texture packs or mods? We'll need to know anything that you might have changed with regards to Minecraft in order to help you.

Comment: I used the Atlantiumcraft mode and I uninstalled it and I used faithful texture pack and I unistalled too maybe it corrupted. if so how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you've downloaded Minecraft again, you've more than likely just downloaded the launcher.

What you need to do (warning: this will delete any single player worlds), is to delete your `.minecraft` folder from your appdata folder (assuming you run Windows?).

To get to your appdata folder, click on start, run, then type `%APPDATA%` and hit return/click OK. Now simply delete the `.minecraft` folder.

Restart the launcher, and it will redownload all the required files, giving you a clean uncorrupted installation of the game files.

An alternative method, is to simply create a new profile using the launcher, with the profile folder in a new location.